# localtime_r stuck on a lock when called from within signal handler in C on CentOS

Tags: c, linux

Env - C on CentOs, glib 2.5

I call a logging function from within my signal handler.  I think I'm using all async signal safe functions in it.  My signal handler gets called twice and gets locked on localtime_r.
What do I need to do to resolve this?

My logging functions shown below.  I apologize if the formatting is off.

```
/**
 * Following async signal safe functions are used
 * fstat, time, localtime_r, asctime_r, rename, open, write, close
 *
 */

void sysLog( Sint8 *fname, Sint32 tskId, Sint32 logType, const char *format, ...)

{

FILE          *fp;

   time_t        sysTime;

   va_list       args;

   struct stat   fStat;

   mode_t        usrMask;

   Sint8         tmpStg[256];

   char         newFileName[256];

   char         localtimestamp[256];

   struct       tm newtime;

   int pfd;

   //-- to sprintf base header and main msg into buffers before write
   char logTimeEtc[255];

   char logMainMsg[1000];


    //Startup task must create this file
    if (stat( fname, &fStat ) < 0)
      if(errno!= ENOENT)
        return;

    //-- Get the local time
    time( &sysTime);
    localtime_r(&sysTime, &newtime);
    asctime_r(&newtime, localtimestamp );
    localtimestamp[24]=0;//remove line feed

    //clear user file and dir permissions
    usrMask = umask(0);

    //-- rename file when >10MB
    if (fStat.st_size < (10000000)) {
      if ((pfd = open(fname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND )) == -1){
        printf ("\n**ERR.%s fopen() %s Failed: name=%s  %s >> errno= %d\n",__FUNCTION__, fname, cmnTskName[tskId], strerror(errno), errno);
        return;
      }

    }
    else {
      //-- rename the current file, with current time stamp attached.
      strcpy(newFileName,fname);
      strcat(newFileName,"-");
      strcat(newFileName, (const char *)&localtimestamp[4]);
      rename(fname,newFileName);

      //-- open the file as new now
      if ((pfd = open(fname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)) == -1){
        printf ("\n**ERR.%s fopen() %s Failed: name=%s  %s >> errno= %d\n",__FUNCTION__, fname, cmnTskName[tskId], strerror(errno), errno);
        return;
      }
    }

    umask(usrMask);




    //-- Write initial standard stuff like timestamp, log type etc
    sprintf(logTimeEtc,"%s %s.%s: pid=%d ", &localtimestamp[4], logTypeName[logType],cmnTskName[tskId], getpid());
    write(pfd,logTimeEtc,strlen(logTimeEtc));

    //-- write main message
    va_start(args, format);
    vsprintf(logMainMsg, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    write(pfd,logMainMsg,strlen(logMainMsg));

    close(pfd);
}//-- sysLog
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is likely that `localtime_r()` is *not* in fact aysnc signal safe on CentOS.

It's certainly not on the [list of async-signal-safe functions specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04).

Comment: I see. So in my function above, localtime_r and asctime_r are not in the list specified by POSIX. So in that case, it boils down to, how do I get localtime from within a sighandler using async-signal safe functions? because if i just use "time" its not that useful.

Comment: @Amit: The answer, somewhat obviously, is "you don't". You need to restructure your code so that you won't need to call localtime_r() from the signal handler. Say, make the signal handler set some flag and do the formatting later.

Comment: None of the stuff you're doing in your signal handler is async-signal-safe.

Comment: ok.  I'll just stop calling logging function in that case from the signal handler. Thanks for all your help guys.